# 'now' not working when using range query for seaching

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "range": {
        "LogTime": {
            "gte": "now-1d",
            "lte": "now",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "top_aggs": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "LogTime",
            "interval": "1h",
            "offset": 0,
            "order": {
                "_key": "asc"
            },
            "keyed": false,
            "min_doc_count": 0
        }
    }
}
```

}

'LogTime' field is date type and has format of yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss.

The query above is to retrieve some logs that is between two dates(from yesterday to today)

So, I used date math, now-1d and now.
However  ElasticSearch give me back nothing.

The result is

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
   "top_aggs": {
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

If I give exact time value, for example 2018-11-26_00:00:000 instead of now and now-1d, ElasticSearch gives the log information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from usin `now` you can use DateTime.now().getMillis(), This will give you the current time stamp that will be more exact.

And to subtract one day from it, use:

```
DateTime.now().getMillis() - (24*60*60*1000)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using Date Math you are getting a yesterday's date with the time when the query is executed. So assuming current date time (i.e. `now`) is `2018-11-27_08:38:10` `now-1d` will not round it down to `2018-11-26_00:00:00`. Use `now-1d/d` to round it down. To understand more on how rounding works refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_math_and_rounding). So the query should be :

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "range": {
        "LogTime": {
            "gte": "now-1d/d",
            "lte": "now/d",
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming now is `2018-11-27_08:38:10` the above will return all the records of date `2018-11-26` and `2018-11-27`